# Why is IE making multiple requests

Tags: java, internet-explorer, web

Has anyone seen this before? I have a Java servlet which returns a non-html document (mp3) and I see IE sends multiple requests to it even though I made the request only once.   The issue is that the subsequent requests have different sessions ids which fail my authentication.

Comment: One possibility `<a href="..." onclick="...">`causing two loads. Then there is an IFRAME issue. This rings a bell. BTW seen in which IE version?

Comment: I saw it with IE9 - it's the only version I have for testing right now. It's not using any iframe, the originating click event just does window.open(url to resource )

Comment: And the click event is better not on a a-href? I am a bit out of the JS specifics, due to jquery and co. Maybe consume the event, return 0/1 or so.

Comment: No it's a non submitting button. If I just take the url and paste I also see multiple requests. I'm guessing IE is doing this for some reason and I hope I can find a response header to stop it. ;)

Comment: Try do it on a `<div>`.. A href with type="audio" with the url in href (without onclick) would be feasible too. CSS can do the view.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried it - same issue. For whatever reason IE wants to send multiple requests. The other requests are missing the JSESSIONID.

Comment: Have you tried using the F12 network tools (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx) or Telerik Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace the request(s)?

Comment: IE F12 shows nothing about the extra requests but Fiddler does. There are extra requests being made without the JSESSONID from IE for whatever reason.